# Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

My migration is as follows:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :male
      t.boolean :admin

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

When I go to script/console and type "User", Rails does not recognize the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you run `script/generate model User ...` or `script/generate migration CreateUser...`?

If you do not generate the model, it won't be available in the console, as Rails doesn't know it exists.

Rails also does not create a `modelname_id` field, it simply creates an `id` field which autoincrements.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

1) The migration will create an auto-incrementing "id" column. (I've never seen a migration create a class_id column unless it was specified).

2) You will need to declare this class in a app/model/user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #class methods go here
end
```

More importantly I want to recommend the [restful_authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master) plugin. It's the community standard for user authentication (meaning it's battle tested, regularly updated, and conforms to most use cases).